# why Pydantic construcor only accepts model_dump - error Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of

Tags: python, pydantic

I have some pydantic classes and try to construct objects using the constructor.
i get this error:

```
>       part: PartOut = PartOut(type="battery", position="l", correlation_timestamp=datetime.now().isoformat(), kpis=kpis)
E       pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for PartOut
E       kpis
E         Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of KpiValues [type=model_type, input_value=KpiValues(values=[KPIValu...hase=None, stage=None)]), input_type=KpiValues]
```

first notice it tells i should input `instance of KpiValues` but as you see i exactly putting this in.

here is the code how i construct the object:

```
kpi: KPIValue = KPIValue(name="somthin'", value=7, timestamp=datetime.now().isoformat())
kpis: KpiValues = KpiValues(values=[kpi])
# an part with one kpi
part: PartOut = PartOut(type="battery", position="l", correlation_timestamp=datetime.now().isoformat(), kpis=kpis)
```

**the code works fine if i give `kpis=kpis.model_dump()` - my question is why i need to do this?**

here is relevant code of pydantic classes:

```
class PartOut(BaseModel):

    # omitting other fields ...
    kpis: KpiValues = Field(..., alias='kpis')

    # validators for other fields
    
    @field_validator('type','kpis', mode='before')
    def convert_none_to_empty_list(cls, v):
        return v if v is not None else []

    model_config = ConfigDict(use_enum_values = True, arbitrary_types_allowed = True, from_attributes = True)

class KpiValues(BaseModel):
    """
    This class represents the values of all KPIs for one part and one point in time.
    It is meant to be used as documents structure for the database (json column).
    """

    values: list[KPIValue]
```

So is there a way to get this working without the need of using `model_dump()`?

Comment: Can you provide a complete runnable example? From what you shared I could not reproduce your error...